# How to select from a HTML5 datalist with Selenium

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-datalist

I'm trying to select from a datalist but only the first element in the list seems to be selectable.

This is a HTML snippet:

```
<td>
<input id="applianceFilterTextbox" class="flat" name="applianceFilter" list="applianceNames" value="ROC-1006 - B827EBB5D539" style="width: 100%"/>
<datalist id="applianceNames">
<!-- ngRepeat: app in appliances -->
<option class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="app in appliances" value="ROC-1006 - B827EBB5D539" ng-value="app.DisplayName">ROC-1006 - B827EBB5D539</option>
<!-- end ngRepeat: app in appliances -->
<option class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="app in appliances" value="ROC-1007 - B827EBD15125" ng-value="app.DisplayName">ROC-1007 - B827EBD15125</option>
<!-- end ngRepeat: app in appliances -->
<option class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="app in appliances" value="ROC-1008 - B827EB05DEF3" ng-value="app.DisplayName">ROC-1008 - B827EB05DEF3</option>
<!-- end ngRepeat: app in appliances -->
<option class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="app in appliances" value="ROC-1009 - B827EB2A379C" ng-value="app.DisplayName">ROC-1009 - B827EB2A379C</option>
<!-- end ngRepeat: app in appliances -->
</datalist>
</td>
```

My module is as follows:

```
public void SelectApplianceFromDatalist(int index)
{
    ExplicitWait.waitElementToBeClickable(driver, 25, appliancesFilterTextBox);
    appliancesFilterTextBox.Clear();
    appliancesFilterTextBox.Click();
    string select1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='applianceNames']/option['" + index + "']")).GetAttribute("value");
    index++;
    string select2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='applianceNames']/option['" + index + "']")).GetAttribute("value");
    index++;
    string select3 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='applianceNames']/option['" + index + "']")).GetAttribute("value");
    index++;
    string select4 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='applianceNames']/option['" + index + "']")).GetAttribute("value");

    appliancesFilterTextBox.SendKeys(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='applianceNames']/option['"+ index +"']")).GetAttribute("value"));
}
```

The select1,select2,select3 and select4 are only present for debug purposes. When calling the module with a value of for instance 3 for index they all contain the value of the first option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the simple method `sendKeys()` to send your required value like -

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("applianceFilterTextbox")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("applianceFilterTextbox")).sendKeys("ROC-1008 - B827EB05DEF3");
```

It will clear the default selected value and enter your required value.

Other thing is that I think you are using right approch but there is minor mistake in your `XPath`. Do change

```
By.XPath("//*[@id='applianceNames']/option['" + index + "']")
```

to

```
By.XPath("//*[@id='applianceNames']/option["+ index +"]")
```

Comment: Because I don't know what the required value is I can not use the simple sendKeys() method as you suggested. But you were right about the minor mistake in the XPath expression. After I removed the simple leading quotes my method is working fine.

Comment: The accepted answer does not address how to search in a datalist when only using the beginning of an item text as search term.

Comment: @Andres, I'm not getting your comment and objection about the accepted answer . If you have any question then feel free to post on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way as well to test the functionality of datalist in textbox:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("applianceFilter")).click();
 
List<WebElement> eleList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"applianceNames\"]/option"));

eleList.forEach(it-> {
                if (it.getAttribute("value").contentEquals("ROC-1007 - B827EBD15125")) { 
driver.findElement(By.name("applianceFilter")).sendKeys(it.getAttribute("value"));
                }
  });
```